Is there a way to get the last Matplotlib figure?
I have a front end that called a package with the name streamlit where it will generate latest Matplotlib object if I called the function st.pyplot().
However, I would like to get the actual fig object because I would like to stored that separately. The problem I am facing is that the fig is created by another package called Pandasai. (i.e., I never needed to import the matplotlib package).
So basically I want to find the fig object globally in my environment.
I tried to import the Matplotlib but I don't think that's the right solution because it may just cover the actual object.
I also tried to use plt.gcf() and append the object to the messages in this manner
a = plt.gcf()

st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": a})

But the graph becomes an empty space after I ask the pandasai to generate another graph

Actually we can first use global find and then just saved it as an image and append it to the message
                figure  = plt.gcf().canvas
                ag = figure.switch_backends(FigureCanvasAgg)
                ag.draw()
                A = np.asarray(ag.buffer_rgba())
                img = Image.fromarray(A)
                st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": img})


This question is similar to: ipython : get access to current figure(). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
